# How to change colour styles for tab navigator in react native?

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

I am a newbie to react native. I am using a tab navigator for my home screen and couldn't understand how to change the active and inactive tab colour styling.

```
export const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Asset: {
   screen: AssetScreen
  },
 Sensors: {
  screen: sensorsStack
 },
 Settings: {
  screen: settingStack
 },
},{
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
animationEnabled: true,
swipeEnabled:false,
tabBarOptions: {
upperCaseLabel: false,
showIcon: true,
activeBackgroundColor:'#2394C7',
inactiveBackgroundColor:'grey',
tabStyle:{
    marginTop:10,
    height :53,
    borderRightWidth:1
},
labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight:'bold',
     marginTop: 0,
     color :'#ffffff'
  },
 },
});
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **activeBackgroundColor** and **inactiveBackgroundColor** property under **tabBarOptions** to set colour for active and inactive tabs.

Please see the document for more info [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab).

Comment: These two properties (activeBackgroundColor, inactiveBackgroundColor) worked for me to colour 'active' and 'inactive' tabs. Even I tried with your **tabBarOptions** (edited one) and it worked as expected.

Comment: I checked it in iOS only, did not check in Android.

Comment: its working in ios but couldnt find it in android. Is there anyway to do it on both the devices.

Comment: Yes, in android it not working, u need to add more styles for android. I have added styles like 
`indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#2394C7',
        height: 53
      },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'grey'
      }`
under `tabBarOptions` and its working fine. Take look at the android issue (
https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1485)